# How can PHP Extract Text from PDF

Tags: php, pdf, text, converters, pdftotext

I need to convert a pdf to text in my php code  i used php class pdfToText but this class does not work with all pdf like scanned pdf because scanned pdf is like a image is there any other method that can help me ?

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>my page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
     <header><h1></h1></header>
        <?php 
            include("PdfToTextmaster/PdfToText.phpclass");
            $pdf = new PdfToText ( '1.pdf' );
            $data = $pdf ->Text;
            echo $data ;
        ?>
  </body>
  <footer></footer>
</html>
```

Comment: you need OCR (but the accuracy depends on the quality of your scanned image and other factors). Normally the steps will (1) first be convert your pdf to jpg files and then (2) process each page by OCR.

Comment: hi ken lee thanks for responding 
I thought in this solution by using  tesseract ocr to process images but first I need to convert the pdf file to jpg can you give me solution to that please ,I am stuck here

Comment: Use Imagick [reference_convert_pdf_to_multiple_jpg_files](https://arjunphp.com/convert-pdf-jpeg-php/)

Comment: If it is an option, you could consider using something like the LEADTOOLS Cloud Services (Disclaimer: I am an employee of the vendor)  which provide Web API methods that support text extraction from scanned images. The [ExtractText](https://services.leadtools.com/documentation/tutorials/php-extracttext-tutorial) API can be used with PHP, for example. An online demo can also be tried [here](https://services.leadtools.com/demo).